# Word for "costs distributed across the sale of many units"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word related to economies of scale, in business. I first heard of it in the context of military equipment being very expensive. This is because the the huge R&D cost is "word" over many units.

"The expense is ... over many items sold" and "the ... expense" when referring to the expense itself.

It's similar to "distributed over..." but I believe it starts with an "A".

Comment: Probably *amortized.*

Comment: That's it! Thanks @Xanne. What is the etiquette for this StackExchange? Should I close the question?

Comment: @Xanne Should post that as an answer, with supporting evidence such as a dictionary excerpt.